# Wordpress Create pages on theme activation - add child pages using this function

Tags: wordpress

I am using this function to add new pages on theme activation:

```
/*************************************************
** Add home page
*************************************************/

if (isset($_GET['activated']) && is_admin()){
        $new_page_title = 'Home';
        $new_page_content = '';
        $new_page_template = 'template-home.php';
        $page_check = get_page_by_title($new_page_title);
        $new_page = array(
                'post_type' => 'page',
                'post_title' => $new_page_title,
                'post_content' => $new_page_content,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1,
        );
        if(!isset($page_check->ID)){
                $new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
                if(!empty($new_page_template)){
                        update_post_meta($new_page_id, '_wp_page_template', $new_page_template);
                }
        }
}
```

Using up this snippet and I am wanting to create quite a few pages.

I.e

```
/*************************************************
** Add new pages
*************************************************/



/*************************************************
** Add home page
*************************************************/

if (isset($_GET['activated']) && is_admin()){
        $new_page_title = 'Home';
        $new_page_content = '';
        $new_page_template = 'template-home.php';
        $page_check = get_page_by_title($new_page_title);
        $new_page = array(
                'post_type' => 'page',
                'post_title' => $new_page_title,
                'post_content' => $new_page_content,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1,
        );
        if(!isset($page_check->ID)){
                $new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
                if(!empty($new_page_template)){
                        update_post_meta($new_page_id, '_wp_page_template', $new_page_template);
                }
        }
}

/*************************************************
** Add About Us page
*************************************************/

if (isset($_GET['activated']) && is_admin()){
        $new_page_title = 'About Us';
        $new_page_content = 'Coming Soon';
        $new_page_template = 'template-page-with-subnav.php';
        $page_check = get_page_by_title($new_page_title);
        $new_page = array(
                'post_type' => 'page',
                'post_title' => $new_page_title,
                'post_content' => $new_page_content,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1,

        );
        if(!isset($page_check->ID)){
                $new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
                if(!empty($new_page_template)){
                        update_post_meta($new_page_id, '_wp_page_template', $new_page_template);
                }
        }
}

        /*************************************************
        ** Add Meet the Staff
        *************************************************/

        if (isset($_GET['activated']) && is_admin()){
                $new_page_title = 'Meet the staff';
                $new_page_content = 'Coming Soon';
                $new_page_template = 'template-page-with-subnav.php';
                $post_parent = '';
                $page_check = get_page_by_title($new_page_title);
                $new_page = array(
                        'post_type' => 'page',
                        'post_title' => $new_page_title,
                        'post_content' => $new_page_content,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'post_author' => 1,
                        'post_parent' => $post_parent,
                );
                if(!isset($page_check->ID)){
                        $new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
                        if(!empty($new_page_template)){
                                update_post_meta($new_page_id, '_wp_page_template', $new_page_template);
                        }
                }
        }
```

What I would like to know is how to set the post parent on the child pages?

It seems as though the post parent is set with 'post_parent' =>
[  ] // Sets the parent of the new post, if any. Default 0.

But say I am adding about us with this method, then want to add meet the staff in the next function, how do I get the id of meet the staff?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**$new_page_id** holds the ID of the page just created (because the return value of the wp_insert_post function is the post ID of the created post or page).

Currently though this is overwritten each time you create a new page.

So you could use a new variable to store the page ID each time you create a page, i.e. change $new_page_id to $about_page_id, $home_page_id etc. for each page creation. E.g.

```
$about_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
```

Then to be able to set the 'post_parent' you need to **create the parent pages first** so you have the appropriate ID to use for the child pages. And add to the page creation array, e.g.

```
    $new_page = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post_title' => $new_page_title,
            'post_content' => $new_page_content,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => 1,
            'post_parent' => $about_page_id
    );
```